# Trying to make Animated Sprite Class; Sprite Won't Move

Tags: c++, class, sprite, sfml

So, I was trying to create a class in C++ for an animated sprite that uses spritesheets for input, and when trying to move the sprite, it just sort of bounces back. It won't save to the position.

I tried using `.setPostion()` but  that still bounces back to where it was. I have no other methods of moving the sprite implemented, nor updating it or anything else. The part in concern in the member function run, which is void is:

```
//if statement
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
{
    curranim[2] = Right;
    playerSprite.setPosition(playerSprite.getPosition().x + walkingSpeed, 0);
}

window.draw(playerSprite);  
//spritesheet.cpp ends here
```

Now here is my main function:

```
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow Window(sf::VideoMode(900, 600), "RPG");
    animsprite sprite("dragon.png", 1, Window);
    sprite.setWalkSpeed(10);

    sf::Event Event;

    while (Window.isOpen())
    {
        while (Window.pollEvent(Event))
        {
            switch (Event.type) 
            {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                    Window.close();
                    break;
            }
        }

        Window.clear();
        sprite.run(Window);
        Window.display();

    }

    return 0;
 }
```

Will I be stuck to repeating my code forever or is there a fix?

Comment: I'd suggest looking here: http://www.bromeon.ch/libraries/thor/documentation/v2.0/group___animations.html

Comment: I suspect that you're repeatedly creating new sprites in the same position and moving them. Post the rest of that function.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I don't download an additional library

Comment: @moldbnilo ?  Hopefully I'm not, because I don't know that I'm doing that.

Comment: Are you sure that walkingSpeed is greater than zero?

Comment: @sunofkyuss Yes, I explained that it moves and then bounces back.

Comment: Is sprite moving only right or left?

Comment: No, all directions, but not at once.

Comment: Can I see full animsprite class?

Comment: You set the y coordinate to zero when sprite moves right. Im guessing the x coordinate be set to zero when sprite moves up or down. If you want to not change the coordinate of sprite, use playerSprite.getPosition().x or playerSprite.getPosition().y instead of zero.

Comment: @sunofkyuss Tried that, didn't fix anything. Also, this part is literally the only meaningful part of it except the constructor and functions to set Data.

Comment: Still if we can see the full code at least we can speak more certain about problem.

Comment: This basically is the full code that's been worked on @sunofkyuss, the only other part creates the sprite. This is all in a member function of class "animsprite"